# Pandas Dataframe grouping and summarizing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:
df_1:

```
    User    Docs     Pref
    user1   doc1      m1
    user1   doc2      m2
    user1   doc3      m1
    user1   doc4      m3
    user2   doc1      m1
    user2   doc2      m2
    user3   doc1      m3
    user4   doc1      m2
```

I need to get the data frames following:

```
    User    m1Count     m2Count     m3Count
    user1     2           1           1
    user2     1           1           0
    user3     0           0           1
    user4     0           1           1
```

I tried to use `value_counts` but couldn't to get what I want.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "User": ["user1", "user1", "user1", "user1","user2","user2","user3","user4"],
        "Docs": ["doc1", "doc2", "doc3", "doc4", "doc1", "doc2","doc1","doc1"],
        "Pref": ["m1", "m2", "m1", "m3", "m1", "m2", "m3", "m2"],
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with `value_counts` and `unstack`:

```
df.groupby("User")["Pref"].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

```
Pref   m1  m2  m3
User             
user1   2   1   1
user2   1   1   0
user3   0   0   1
user4   0   1   0
```

If you want to clean the column and index names:

```
(
    df.groupby("User")["Pref"]
    .value_counts()
    .unstack()
    .fillna(0)
    .astype(int)
    .rename_axis(None)
    .rename_axis(None, axis="columns")
    .add_suffix("Count")
)
```

```
       m1Count  m2Count  m3Count
user1        2        1        1
user2        1        1        0
user3        0        0        1
user4        0        1        0
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use melt method of Pandas . it convert unique values of a column into a column name then you can combine or group by to know the account

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-melt/

```
Df.pivot(index=['User','Docs'], columns ='Pref', values = 'Pref').groupby('User').count()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a crosstab operation. Pandas has a built-in function for it. Add a suffix to column names, remove axis names and you're done. Read more about how it relates to `groupby` and `pivot` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe/73060100#73060100) (the other operations used in the other answers).

```
(
    pd.crosstab(df['User'], df['Pref'])
    .add_suffix('Count')
    .reset_index()
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

[image: result]